# PHP Backend How can I delete MySql entry after x Seconds?

Tags: php

I want to create a registration system that gives users 120 seconds to verify their registration via email. If the user fails to do this in time the MySql entry that has been made for this registration must be deleted automatically.

EDIT: Cronjob is out of the question. The MySql entry needs to be deleted exactly 120 seconds after the registration has been issued by the client. A cronjob cannot do that.

I've experimented with sleep but I cannot get the result I want, something like this

```
<?php
$seconds = 0;
add();
function add() {
    $seconds++;
    if($seconds < 6 ) {
        sleep(1);
        add();
    }   
    echo $seconds;
}
?>
```

is not working out as I expected. The recursive function creates an infinite loop for some reason.

Is there a way to request php to execute a function after said 120 seconds without using sleep. Idealy the user should not notice the timer going in the backend it shouldn't affect him at all.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Why not use a cronjob for this? That would work way better than such a blocking code

Comment: I thought of that but I do not really know anything about cronjobs in php. I figured that maybe there is a simpler method? If not I would be happy for an example using cronjob.

Comment: There are tons of tutorials out there, why not read any of those :) Especially if the first process (using your code) dies or timeouts or fails, a cronjob running each one or two minutes to clear out registration attempts works

Comment: Yes, I looked into it. Cronjob is still not what I want. The validation time needs to be 120 seconds from the moment on the registration happens. A cronjob would not be able to do that.

Comment: You can check it when the user attempts to submit the verification - if the time has elapsed at that moment, then your code can simply refuse to accept the verification info. You don't need a timed task to auto-update the database. (You could also then have a "cleanup" cron job which runs on a schedule to delete any records which didn't get verified in time). P.S. 2 minutes is pretty harsh...what's the reason for that? Often, emails can take a lot longer than that to even be delivered, for many reasons which are not under your (or the recipient's) control.

Comment: (As an aside, recursion makes no real sense for the sleep thing you were trying to do - a while loop would be sufficient, or just `sleep(120);`. But this code will block your server so it's a really bad idea. And the infinite loop was because you forgot to put `global $seconds;` at the start of the function - global variables aren't automatically imported into function scope.)

Comment: Thanks @ADyson I will do it like that then. About the 2min: How much time do you think should I give the user then? How about 20min or is this still too short?

Comment: A day or two is pretty normal. Maybe depends a bit on the type of site and the sensitivity of the information, but realistically you need to allow for delays in sending emails, connectivity issues, people simply having other "offline" things they need to do in the meantime, etc. Also provide the option to re-send the email if they don't receive it - that's pretty common functionality these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it when the user attempts to submit the verification - if the time has elapsed at that moment, then your code can simply refuse to accept the verification info. You don't need a timed task to auto-update the database.

(You could also then have a "cleanup" cron job which runs on a schedule to delete any records which didn't get verified in time).